# Styling :collection_check_boxes RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

I have a collection check box

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name %>
```

I wanted to style them in any of those http://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm

How would I add a class for that?

I've tried these so far:

```
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <%= b.check_box(class: "squaredFour")%>
   <%end%>
```

and

```
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name, {:item_wrapper_class => 'squaredFour' %>
```

it doesn't seem to work. Anyone know a fix? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<% f.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
  <%= b.label { b.check_box(class: "squaredFour") } %>
<% end %>
```

You have to pass the b.check_box as a block to b.label, and you can also add params to b.label if you wish to style the label e.g.

```
b.label(class: "some_class")
```

It's all explained here in the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes

Comment: This seems to have the same effect as when i did this

    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <%= b.check_box(class: "squaredFour")%>
    <%end%>

And all my Tags on the page went missing

Comment: Try to remove the = from the first statement e.g. make it:

<% f.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name do |b| %>

I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay I tried it without the %, neither the box or the tag shows up. Before with the %, the box showed up but not the tag

Comment: It was without the =, not %.

Comment: Sorry I meant without the =